# Do all compact manifolds admit geodesic tiling

Tags: co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold.  I'll call a set of non-empty subsets $C_1,\dots,C_N$ a *geodesic tiling* of $M$ if:

- Each $C_n$ is closed (geodesically) convex hull of a finite number of $\{p_{i,n}\}_{i=1}^{k_n}$ in $C_n$; i.e. the smallest geodesically convex subset of $M$ containing the points $\{p_{i,n}\}_{i=1}^{k_n}$,
- $\cup_{n=1}^N\, C_n=M$
- If $n\neq n'$ then $C_n$ and $C_{n'}$ have disjoint interiors.

It seems to me intuitive that such a collection of sets $\{C_n\}_{n=1}^N$ must exist.  But does it?  And where can I find a reference?

Comment: Why did you introduce $r$? I don't see it being used anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If dimension $=2$, then "yes".

If dimension $\ge 3$, then "no".
If such a tiling would exist, then the common boundary of a pair of $C$'s  would contain a geodesic hypersurface, but generic Riemannian manifold does not have such hypersurfaces.

For more on convex hulls in Riemannian world, see [our paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15189).

Comment: If I just require that the sets $C_n$ are closed, non-empty, and geodesically convex (instead of being the hulls of finitely many points) then is this possible.  E.g. this is certainly now possible for any $n$-sphere by taking the north and south hemispheres (For all $n>1$).

Comment: Since this is a different question; I pose it here as a natural-follow up to this lively discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427683/when-can-a-compact-metric-space-be-covered-by-finitely-many-nearly-disjoint-clos

Comment: @AIM I did not use that $C_i$ are hulls of finitely many points.

Comment: Cant you just take the cover whose only element is the whole manifold. That cover should have all the desired properties.

Comment: @HenrikRüping, sure, but this is the only one for a generic connected Riemannian manifold of dimension $\ge 3$.

Comment: @HenrikRüping Ah but by geodesically convex, i mean that there is a unique geodesic connecting any two points in that set, so that doesn't work for me.