# When can a compact metric space be covered by finitely many nearly-disjoint closed and convex sets?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, metric-spaces

This question is a follow-up of the [following negative question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427657/do-all-compact-manifolds-admit-geodesic-tiling).

Let $(X,d)$ be a (non-empty) compact metric space.

---

More generally than in the first post, I'll call a set of non-empty subsets $C_1,\dots,C_N$ a *geodesic tiling* of $M$ if:

- Each $C_n$ is closed and [geodesically-convex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geodesic+convexity#in_a_metric_space)

  - *(but not necessarily the geodesically convex hull of a finite number of points),*
- $\cup_{n=1}^N\, C_n=X$
- If $n\neq n'$ then $C_n$ and $C_{n'}$ have disjoint interiors.

---

When does $(X,d)$ admit such a cover?

If the question is too general, what about when $(X,d)$ is a compact subset of Euclidean space?

Comment: The Euclidean space can be subdivided into cubes, it induces the needed subdivision for $X$. (Or, did you want to use induced intrinsic metric?)

Comment: The space $X$ must have a lot of geodesic hypersurfaces, but it is hard to make precise what is "a lot". Among sufficient conditions: $X$ is Riemannian and has constant sectional curvature.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin For the Riemannian case, if I'm allowed to take any *other* metric generating the same topology as the innducws intrinsic metric (possibly non-equivalent metrics) is there hope in dimension above 3?